# How to display the good subscription ? Meteor JS

Tags: meteor

I got a little subscription problem who doesn't stop when it must.

### Context:

I have a tweets collection, that I display to my client with a publication/subscription process.
Here is my publication:

```
Meteor.publish('tweets', function(params) {
    return Tweets.find({hashtag: params});
});
```

You can see I have an hashtag to sort them, and only display the tweets with a specified hastag.
Here is my client code with the subscription:

```
var sub;
Template.hashtagPage.rendered = function() {
    // Get the hashtag of the current page
    hashtag = document.getElementById('hashtag').innerHTML; 
    sub = Meteor.subscribe('tweets', hashtag);
};

Template.hashtagPage.destroyed = function(){
    sub.stop();
};
```

In my template, I display every tweets got with the subscription. I get the same template for each page which display tweets.

But here is my problem. When I first go to a page wich display the tweets with the hashtag **#first**, I get them without problems. But if next I go to a page which display the tweets with the hashtag **#second**, my client display the tweets with the hashtag **#first** and **#second**.

### What I'm thinking

Normally, the .stop() on a subscription is supposed to remove the subscription data from the client's cache (docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe). But I don't. I've tried to change the position of the sub.stop(). It works when it's on the same template function as the subscription, but then, no tweets are displayed.

#### How do I stop the subscription to only show the goods tweets with the good hashtag in my client page ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a session variable. You shouldn't have to rerun the subscription once it's setup. Reactive variables from Meteor to the rescue.

`Template.hashtagPage.rendered = function() {
    // Get the hashtag of the current page
    Meteor.subscribe('tweets', Session.get('hashtag'));
};`

`Template.hashtagPage.events {
  'blur #hashtag': function(event) {
    Session.set('hashtag', event.target.val());
  }
};`

Normally I'd put the subscription in the route (using iron-router) with waitOn

Comment: I don't understand your template.hashtagPage.event, espacially the 'blur #hashtag' and the event.target.val()

Comment: Since you are grabbing the hashtag out of a HTML element, I was guessing that #hashtag is an input element. Even if not, you could add an input to the page that allows the user to change the hashtag (which would then re-run the subscription).

Comment: Does the above work and remove tweets associated with the old hashtag?    My understanding is that this will both keep old data and create a leak on the server with a new subscription every time 'hashtagPage' is rendered.  You should at least add a handle and call stop before each subscribe. Doing that will still be inefficient if the subscribes have any overlapping data.

Comment: Made a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/mikowals/9676242) and added facts package to show leak.  Calling stop inside the render prevents the leak but also keeps data off of the client since render tends to fire more than once.

Answer (score 0):

The more standard way to do this is by making your subscription argument a Session variable and using Deps.autorun() to start and stop the appropriate subscription.

In your rendered function:

```
Session.set( "hashTag", hashTag);
```

And in toplevel client code:

```
Deps.autorun( function(){
   Meteor.subscribe( 'tweets', Session.get("hashTag") );
});
```

The autorun function will call stop on the old subscription handle when the Session variable updates.  This is mentioned in the [docs for subscribe](http://devel-docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe).

If you do want to manage starting and stopping the subscription yourself make sure each subscription handle is getting stored in its own variable, like `subHandles[ hashTag ]`, otherwise you may overwrite a handle you need before calling stop on it.

Comment: What do you mean by toplevel Client code ? The rendered function? Or just code written in client/main.js ?